# Наличие тега в XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Как можно проверить с помощью js(JQuery) наличие тега, к примеру, `<Start></Start>` в xml-файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if ($('start').length > 0) {
  //есть
}
```